# Responsive Filemanager doesn't upload files bigger than ~2MB

Tags: file-upload, filesize, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I use Responsive Filemanager for several websites that I host. I have the latest version (9.6.6) installed, and I also use the tinyMCE plugin for the Jquery tinyMCE version 4, but my problem occurs with both the standalone filemanager as well as the plugin, so I doubt this is important.

Anyhow, my problem is the following: everything seems to be working just fine when I upload files smaller than *exactly* 2 megabytes. Using a dummy file generator, I have been able to generate a PFD file of exactly 2097152 bytes, which uploads fine, and a PDF file of 2097153 bytes, which doesn't upload.
Responsive Filemanager always says the upload went fine (with both the Standard Uploader and the JAVA uploader), but any file bigger than 2097152 bytes doesn't actually get uploaded.

Here's a video demonstrating precicely what the problem is: https://youtu.be/NDtZHS6FYvg

Since my RF config allows files up to 100MB (see entire config here: http://pastebin.com/H9fvh1Pg), I'm guessing it might be something with my server settings? I'm using XAMPP for Windows. Could it be that there are some settings in my Apache config or something like that, which block uploads through http bigger than 2MB?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: typo's and added links + video showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution for my own problem. I couldn't believe some sort of bug would cause any file exactly bigger than 2 MB to fail, so after a while I finally figured out it had to be something with the server itself, and indeed, in the php.ini I found the following line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Changing this to a bigger number fixed the problem for me. Would be nice if ResponsiveFileManager had a way of informing the user about the fact that the upload did in fact **not** complete successfully due to a php.ini server setting, but ah well...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the config file of responsivefilemanager, i.e config.php

```
    'MaxSizeUpload' => 10,
```

Just change the `MaxSizeUpload` variable and check.